# Calling JavaScript function through another method

Tags: javascript, dom-events

There is a JavaScript function that is normally called through a form tag, using `onsubmit`.

In the code it looks like this:

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
```

If I were going to call the validate function through some other method, what variable would I pass it? I mean, the 'this' in the `onsubmit` call, what would I put there instead? Would it be the id of the form, so "form1"?

Comment: What do you mean by "some other method"?  Also, can you give us more info on the validate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the element that the tag creates, that is, the form element. So you would call it with:

```
validate(document.getElementById('form1');
```

For more information on events, check out [this introduction](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). The onsubmit attribute you're using is an [inline event handler](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html).

Answer (score 0):

`this` in that context is the DOM element(the form)

So you should use it like this:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form1');
validate(form);
```

Comment: if not through a submit button, you can allways use form1.submit(); or to be more correct document.getElementById('form1').submit();

Comment: @Frank. What are you talking about?

Comment: I'm saying maybe he can just trigger it whenever he wants to call it.

Comment: @Frank. I don't know what he wants, maybe you should comment to him. Place your comment on the question.